# Can you say "using derivations from a mathematical equation"?

Tags: mathematics

if I mean to say I took existing equations and derived from them more equations, what is the the correct way to say it?

using derivations from a mathematical equation

or

using derivations of a mathematical equation

or

something else..

thanks!

Comment: Can you show the complete sentence you're trying to write please?

Comment: Using derivations from Rall's cable equations, we found the variable.

Comment: I think most likely you should be [*using **derivatives** of (some existing formulae).*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=using+derivations+of%2Cusing+derivatives+of&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cusing%20derivations%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cusing%20derivatives%20of%3B%2Cc0) But perhaps a professional mathematician would say otherwise for your exact context. If you're lucky, Peter Shore may pitch in here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Doesn't work, unfortunately, because *derivative* has a specific technical meaning (having to do with the Calculus -- think Newton, Leibnitz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would phrase it as "using equations derived from Rall's Cable equations."  If you're working from known or named equations you should reference them specifically.  I would avoid the word 'derivative' except when referring specifically to that calculus operation.  Depending on the mathematical maturity of the intended audience, I might also avoid the word 'derivation' in an attempt to avoid the reader thinking I meant 'derivative'.

As a side note, in some areas of mathematics, such as Ring Theory, the word 'derivation' also has a well defined meaning (it's similar to a derivative).

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the nouns "derivation" or "derivative" may easily be confused with the calculus operation of derivatives, but the verb "to derive" is recognized as a more general term. For example, I had an engineering professor who spent most of our classes deriving formulas, as in, he spent class time finding the origin of or related equations to the focus of the topic. For your sentence, "We derived the variable from Rall's cable equations" or "The variable was derived from Rall's cable equations" would indicate that Rall's cable equations led to the solution for the variable.

Comment: I agree with all of this except that "derivation" is also fine.  It's just "derivates" that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would show the final equation(s) you arrived at after doing your further manipulations.  First you show the original equation(s), then you gloss over the details but give the basic outline of how you manipulated them to get to the next step.

In general terms, you can say that you will be deriving a more useful form of the standard equation(s) by performing, for example a u-substitution.  Or by applying such-and-so methods.

Answer (score 0):

> using derivations from a mathematical equation
>
> or
>
> using derivations of a mathematical equation

The latter implies exactly what it says: derivations OF a mathematical equation. Namely, it refers to the process according to which one derived the equation in question from some other equation or set of equations. So it would incorrect if that's not what you intend to say. Based on my interpretation of what you intend to say, I would say it's incorrect.

The former is not incorrect, but it's odd. It's not the way a mathematician would speak: any number of equations can be derived from any given starting equation. A mathematician would say something along these lines:

> From X, I derived Y.
>
> Starting with X, I derived Y.
>
> One can derive Y from X as follows ...
>
> The derivation of Y from X involves ...

There are any number of possibilities.

*Derivation* of X from Y means that from X one derives Y, that X is a starting point and Y is the end point.